# StreamWriter Sometimes Clears My File

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm making a program to add/remove entries to the Windows hosts file. So far it works fine except sometimes when I remove an item using my form, it will clear the entire hosts file, leaving nothing.

Here is my code:

```
 public void removeFromHosts(String key)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(key);
        if (key != "" || key != " ")
        {
            String[] strings = new String[1000];

            String all = File.ReadAllText(hostFile);

            strings = all.Split('\n');


            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(hostFile);

            foreach (String s in strings)
            {
                if (s != "255.255.255.255 " + key + " #Blocked by MyProgram")
                {
                    writer.Write(s);

                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text += s;
                }
            }



            writer.Close();

            blockurls.SelectedItems[0].Remove();

            MessageBox.Show("URL Successfully removed");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty");
        }
    }
```

I'm basically checking each line in the textfile to see if it contains the url, if it doesn't contain the url then write that line to the file. What could be causing it to wipe the entire file?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are checking if the entry "contains" the value entered. However, this would be dangerous.  In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) it states that if you pass it an empty string, contains will always return true. If the key is empty string, all lines will be removed. Also, If your key is something like "a" then all entries with an a will be be removed.  Perhaps you should be checking if the string equals the key, or do some more complex kind of check. I assume you're entering the hostname as the key, pick apart the line, and ensure that the host name matches the value in the key.

You could probably fix your code by replacing the contains with something like

```
s = "255.255.255.255 " + key
```

Or maybe

```
Regex.IsMatch(s,"^255\.255\.255\.255\s+" + Regex.Escape(key) + "\s*$")
```

Comment: I updated the contains check to be a little more specific. seems to remove the well, but still removes all of the entries sometimes.

Comment: Again if key is empty, it will remove all entries with 255.255.255.255 at the beginning. You probably want to check if the value is empty before attempting.

Comment: I checked to see if s = the the full string which you can see in the updated the code above.

Comment: You're checking if it contains, not if it equals.

Comment: If it's still emptying out the file, it's probably best to run it using the debugger and step through it line by line to see if there's anything unexpected going on.  My best guess would be that it's crashing before closing the file. Causing you to end up with an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using this code:

public void removeFromHosts(String key)
        {

```
            ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(hostFile);

            while (reader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                strings.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            }


            reader.Close();

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(hostFile);

            foreach (String s in strings)
            {
                if (!s.Contains("255.255.255.255 " + key + " #Blocked by Parental Care"))
                {
                    writer.Write(s + "\n");

                }
            }



            writer.Close();

            blockurls.SelectedItems[0].Remove();

            MessageBox.Show("URL Successfully removed");

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `File.ReadAllLines()` ?

Comment: Thats what i was using before. This works now and I don't want to change it.